# Google Fit Workout/Exercise reader

Tags: android, kotlin, google-fit

I have tried

```
val dataRequest = DataReadRequest.Builder()
                    .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
                    .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
                    .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
                    .read(DataType.TYPE_WORKOUT_EXERCISE)
                    .read(DataType.AGGREGATE_MOVE_MINUTES)
                    .read(DataType.TYPE_MOVE_MINUTES)
                    .setTimeRange(start2B , end2B , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .enableServerQueries()
                    .bucketByActivitySegment(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .build()

 Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, account)
                    .readData(dataRequest)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                         for (bucket in it.buckets) {
                            for (data in bucket.dataSets) {
                                for (point in data.dataPoints) {
                                    when (point.dataType) {
                                        DataType.AGGREGATE_DISTANCE_DELTA   -> distanceTotal.add(   point.getValue(Field.FIELD_DISTANCE).asFloat()          )
                                        DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM        -> heartRateTotal.add(  point.getValue(Field.FIELD_BPM).asFloat()               )
                                        DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED     -> caloriesTotal.add(   point.getValue(Field.FIELD_CALORIES).asFloat()          )
                                        DataType.TYPE_WORKOUT_EXERCISE      -> exerciseNames.add(  "[${point.getValue(Field.FIELD_EXERCISE).asString()}]   ")
                                        DataType.TYPE_MOVE_MINUTES          -> Log.i("GOOGLE-FIT", "Move Minutes          $point     ")
                                        DataType.AGGREGATE_MOVE_MINUTES     -> Log.i("GOOGLE-FIT", "Moving Mins  Count    $point     ")
                                    }
                                }
                                Log.i("GOOGLE-FIT", "Google Daily  DATE Read      INFO       A: $distanceTotal          B: $heartRateTotal          C: $caloriesTotal          D: $exerciseNames           ")

                            }
                        }
```

I get calories and distance sometimes,  but never exerciseName
What is the correct way to access exercise/workout  recorded in Google Fit?

Does anyone know of a tutorial/example showing how to get workout data from the Google fit API?

Where can one get google git API support?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may try Sessions API this will let you obtain a list of sessions from the fitness store that match some criteria.

https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-sessions#read-fitness-data

Finally, if you haven't seen this yet, please check out the sample apps to help you get started writing/understanding Fit features in Android.

https://developers.google.com/fit/android/samples